# How can I concatenate using Range method in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am combining two columns and using find method. One worksheet I am using cell and other one Range but when I use range my code doesn't work. I am getting an error. Here is the code below. I am getting Type mismatch Error.

```
 Do While ws1.Cells(count, 1).Value <> ""
    Set comparisonCell = ws2.Range("D:D") & "" & ws2.Range("C:C").Find(What:=ws1.Cells(count, 4) & "" & ws1.Cells(count, 3))


    If Not comparisonCell Is Nothing Then
    ws1.Cells(count, 6) = comparisonCell.Offset(0, 2)
    count = count + 1
    Else: ws1.Cells(count, 6) = "New"
    count = count + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: `ws2.Range("D:D") & ...` is trying to take a full column as the start of the concatenation. Even if your `Find` was successful, this is a type mismatch. You need one cell from that column. You're also trying to `Set` a range object to a concatenated string. Please provide a better explanation of what you're trying to do.